# How to implement multiple connection to different active-directory server using nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, active-directory

I am working on an active directory and every thing is working fine for a single configuration for a Active directory using npm package 'ad'. The following is my config for ad instance in config.js:

```
const config = {
  url: process.env.AD_IS_SECURE !== 'false' ? 
 `ldaps://${process.env.AD_IP}:${process.env.AD_PORT}` : `ldap://${process.env.AD_IP}`,
  user: process.env.AD_USER,
  pass: process.env.AD_PASS
}

var ActiveDirectory = function(){
try{
   if (!config.url) throw 'Not a valid url';
   if (!config.user) throw 'Not a valid user';
   if (!config.pass) throw 'Not a valid pass';
   return new AD(config);
}catch(e){
   console.error(e);
   throw e;
}
}

export default ActiveDirectory;
```

Moreover, please find the details for active directory config stored in a .env file below:

```
AD_IP='ipaddress'
AD_PORT=389
AD_USER='username'
AD_PASS='password
AD_IS_SECURE=false
```

Now I would like to connect multiple active-directory premises for different IP addresses and credentials, depending on the request from the client. I am using following instance to perform operations on the active directory.

```
var ad = require('./config')

    ad.getUser()
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
    })
```

Please help me out.

Comment: 1. How to implement multiple connections to different active-directory servers using node.js? 2. Are you using the following package? https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory

Comment: No. I am using this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/ad @Wasbeer

Comment: OK. Why would you like to work with multiple AD servers?

Comment: I have a situation where i am giving a option to the user to use their on active directory services rather than default provided one which is our setup of active directory.@Wasbeer

Comment: OK. So would it be possible to create a new instance of AD if the user chooses to use its own AD? If the user chooses to use its own AD, the user and password data could be passed as arguments to the `ActiveDirectory` function and used instead of the `user` and `pass` `config` values? Thinking out loud.